# Seleccionar parte del texto entre simbolos

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un blog.

Mi duda es, supongamos que en el párrafo del articulo del blog, quiero que se pongan en negritas las palabras que estén entre ":" por ejemplo, "Había :una: vez", se que se puede hacer con javascript, pero lo único que encontré al respecto es buscando en el innerHTML una palabra específica y agregándole el span con el estilo.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para agregar ciertos estilos puntualmente a las palabras que estén entre símbolos particulares?

Comment: No se pudo editar mi comentario, sí que lo eliminé.

Answer (score 6):

> ... lo único que encontré al respecto es buscando en el innerHTML una palabra específica y agregándole el span con el estilo....  ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para agregar ciertos estilos puntualmente a las palabras que estén entre símbolos particulares?

En html, no se puede cambiar el estilo de un bloque de texto sin diferenciarlo con una etiqueta.

Considera este ejemplo...

```
<p>Lorem Isup, el diablo is malissimo</p>
```

**No** se puede cambiar el estilo de "el diablo" directamente, pues todo el bloque de texto ("Lorem Isup, el diablo is malissimo") utilizara el mismo estilo.

Lo que ya has encontrado es la forma de modificar el estilo puntual de un cierto texto.

```
// html
<p>Lorem Isup, <span class="bold">el diablo</span> is malissimo</p>

// css 
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

Por ello, puedes usar algo así: Con una regular expression, buscar las diferentes marcas y hacer el remplazo manualmente. Tambien puedes usar markdown standard usando alguna librería bien probada como por ejemplo: https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js

```js
// seleccionas lo que quieres modicar, en este caso 
// use <p> pero puedes usar querySelector para traer
// mas elementos. 
var range = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
  var matched = range[i].textContent.match(/:(.+?):/g)
  if (matched) {
    matched.forEach(function(text) {
      var newtext = text.substring(1, text.length - 1);
      range[i].innerHTML = range[i].innerHTML.replace(text, '<span class="bold">' + newtext + '</span>');
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Isup, :el diablo: is malissimo, :tu sabes:</p>
```

Comment: +1 aunque quizás convendría verificar que no esté adentro de un tag. Podría ser [`.replace( /:([^:<>\n]+):(?![^<]*>)/g, '<span class="bold">$1</span>');`](https://regex101.com/r/wH1eN0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar algo similar a esto:

```
//texto = "Había :una: vez" simbolo = ":"
var cambiarTexto = function (texto, simbolo) { 
while (texto.indexOf(simbolo)>0) {
    var posicionInicial = texto.indexOf(simbolo);
    var posicionFinal = texto.indexOf(simbolo, posicionInicial+1);
    var textoEntreSimboloOriginal = texto.substring(posicionInicial, posicionFinal+1);
    var textoEntreSimbolo = texto.substring(posicionInicial+1, posicionFinal);
    texto = texto.split(textoEntreSimboloOriginal).join("<span class='miestilo'>" + textoEntreSimbolo + "</span>");
}
return texto;// Resultado = Había <span class='miestilo'>una</span> vez   
}
```

luego solo tendrías que modificar el elemento que tiene ese texto que quieres modificar. por ejemplo:

```
var remplazoGeneral = function () {

document.body.innerHTML = cambiarTexto(document.body.innerHTML, ":");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

antes que nada, gracias por los comentarios, queria decirles que encontre una manera, que creo que (al menos para mi) es mas fácil, desde PHP con BBCode.

PHP

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['texto'])){
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
    $texto = stripslashes($texto);
    $texto = htmlspecialchars($texto);
    $texto = nl2br($texto);

    $texto = preg_replace('#\:(.+)\:#isU', '<b>$1</b>', $texto);

    echo $texto;
  }
?>
```

Ese es el codigo que estoy usando, en el 'index.php'.
Explico (como puedo) el codigo.

La función **stripslashes()** quita las barras invertidas de la cadena, en este caso $texto, para no tener conflictos despues con 'preg_replace()'.

La función **htmlspecialchars()** escapa los caractéres epeciales en entidades html, por ejemplo, el caractér **&** lo convierte en **&amp**.

La función **nl2br()** es parecida a htmlspecialchars(), la funcion se leeria 'Ene ele to be ere' jaja, es decir, de alguna manera **\n -> br**, por lo que estas tres funciones, lo que hacen es traducir el string ingresado, en HTML.

Ahora, la mas importante, **preg_replace()**:

Esta función, busca una expresión regular (primer parámetro) y las reemplaza con lo deseado (segundo parametro), explico un poco el primero.

```
'#\:(.+)\:#isU'
```

Voy a explicar (repito, como pueda) el primer parámetro, que es el patrón, este se define entre los **#**.
Luego, se indíca entre *qué* símbolos tiene que estar la expresión a reemplazar, en este caso son los **":"**, y se escapa el caractér con la barra invertida.
Por último, la serie de símbolos **(.+)**, por lo que entiendo, se interpretaría como "cualquier palabra/s", por lo que "Toda la **cadena** que esté entre **:**, va a ser reemplazada por el segundo parámetro. Y finalizamos esta parte del codigo con **#isU** que no voy a explicar porque realmente no lo se, no quiero dar informacion errónea jaja.

Ahora el segundo parámetro, 'Por **que** se va a sustituir el primero'.
Como veran, en mi código utilizé lo siguiente:

```
<b>$1</b>
```

Como pueden ver, donde iría la palabra que queremos que aparezca en negríta, hay un **$1**, basicamente es una variable, que representa la primer expresión regular ingresada.

Esto nos da el pie para el tercér parámetro, la cadena que estabamos utilizando, que en este caso, era **$texto**. No puedo explicar mucho del tercer parametro porque realmente, no estoy seguro como funciona, si alguien quiere aportar algo mas, es bienvenido.

Y en HTML, el formulario es el siguiente:

HTML

```
<form action='index.php' method='POST'>
  <textarea name='texto'></textarea>
  <input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
</form>
```

Cabe aclarar que el **name='texto'** es el valor que se envia a **$_POST['texto']**.

Les pido me tengan piedad con respecto a mi explicación, quise decirlo lo más claro posible, soy un tanto amateur con esto, y particularmente, *BBCode*, lo conocí hace 30 minutos.
Si alguien ve algun error en lo que dije, le pido por favor que me lo aclare, todos aprendemos de nuestros errores, y yo particularmente, a prueba y error!.

Espero que le sirva a alguien, y muchas gracias denuevo a los que me contestaron. Saludos!

Comment: No hace falta escapar los `:`, podés usar `'#:(.+):#isU'`... Esta solución es exactamente lo mismo que te propuso @rnd [en su respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22904/127) usando JavaScript en vez de PHP (y fijate que etiquetaste así la pregunta -no usaste `[php]`)